# Non-medical or slang synonyms for female reproductive organs

Tags: synonyms

I am basically writing an intercourse scene between two characters in a medieval-like setting, so the tone of the book is slightly medieval as well. Now, while I have found plenty of synonyms for the male body parts, I'm having difficulties with the female ones. For some reason, all synonyms in the English language for "vagina" sound rather off-putting.

I cannot use "vulva" because it sounds too clinical (same with "vagina"). "Womb" makes me think of motherhood (which is the last thing I want to come to the readers' minds while reading these scenes) or animals. "Gash" sounds like it would be better used to describe flesh wounds. "Hole" sounds very ominous and generic. Other words like "pussy" or "c*nt" are too slang-ish, even offensive. And euphemism like "love cave" or "Cupid's hole" or anything along those lines sound very childish and even humorous. I was considering "slit" for a while but even that brings slang to mind. I was even considering some sort of milder euphemisms, such as "the wetness between her thighs" but they have already been used in other similar works so I'd rather not.

Just to clarify, I don't need a synonym for a particular part of the female genitalia, just for it as a whole.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What research have you done, and what have you learned?  Oh, hang on, err...

Comment: Why don't you look through scripts of TV shows such as "Rome", "the Tudors", "the Borgias", "the Spartacus", etc. The words you are looking for are there. Believe me!

Comment: For a medieval novel, **hymen** is a possibility, even if anatomically it is a perforated membrane that may cover or partly cover the entrance to the vagina. You may also envisage "matrix", quite a womb synonym.

Comment: Probably "beaver" deserves mention.

Comment: If you are looking for very old slang words, a slang dictionary is a great help. There must be a zillion words for this, many of which are very old, and some of those would no doubt be recognized as the same today.

Comment: You may refer to the following study, see from page 13 : http://andreasgramm.de/papers/Gramm_Sexual_Allusions_in_the_Works_of_William_Shakespeare.pdf

Comment: "Womb" is anatomically incorrect, anyway: the womb and the vagina are separate organs, with the cervix between them.

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you the most. You're not obliged to but I am curious :) Click on the greyed check mark underneath the bottom arrow, to accept an answer.

Comment: D.H.Lawrence faced the same problem. Are the ones he used in *Lady Chatterley's Lover* not suitable? But that was early-twentieth century. When you say *medieval*, that covers about a 1,000 year period between the end of the Roman Empire and the Reformation! Just as a guide, what are the male ones that you settled upon?

Comment: Five years and no feedback - Vagina monologues review?

Answer (score 10):

You might try an authentically medieval English word or two. Chaucer’s Wife of Bath boasts of her own at line 608 of her [Prologue](http://www.luminarium.org/medlit/wifeprologue.htm):

> I hadde the beste **quoniam** myghte be.

Elsewhere (e.g., [Merchant's Tale](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chaucer/teachslf/mert-par.htm#TALE), line 2061), Chaucer quibbles on *queynte* as *(a)* curious, odd, arcane, and *(b)* female pudendum (cognate with *cunt);* at [Miller’s Tale](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chaucer/teachslf/milt-par.htm) 3276–77 he uses these two meanings separately, rhyming the word with itself. *Queynt* is also a variant reading for *quoniam* or *quonyam* in the Wife of Bath’s boast.

Comment: Oh yeah, I keep forgetting that Chaucer wrote quite a bit of sex scenes, should have looked into that sooner :P Thanks for bringing him up.

Comment: That makes me wonder: What is the relation to the biblical  *beati pauperes spiritu* **quoniam** *ipsorum est regnum caelorum* where it means "because"?

Comment: Per OED s.v. *quoniam,* "This use of Latin quoniam may originate in a punning reference to the first line of Psalm 146: Laudate Dominum, quoniam bonus est psalmus ‘Praise the Lord! For it is good to sing praises to our God’ (R. S. V.), although this is far from certain."

Answer (score 9):

Many sources (e.g., [here](http://yaleherald.com/special-issues/consider-the-oyster-a-brief-history-of-aphrodisiac-foods/)) argue a tight connection between *visual similarity* of various foods to genitals and the *aphrodisiac effect* thereof; some even claim that the visual similarity sourced the popular belief in the effect.

One of the most notorious examples is the [***oyster***](http://nymag.com/thecut/2013/08/all-the-ways-to-say-penis.html): across ages and cultures, it is believed to be an aphrodisiac, among other things, because of the visual resemblance and the many alluring connotations of the shell.

This must have been on Shakespeare's mind, too, I think, when he cheerily put

> Why, then the world ’s mine oyster,
>   Which I with sword will open.

into *The Merry Wives of Windsor*.

By the way, a feminist view of *why* it is awkward to find just the right term for an occasion is offered [here](https://debuk.wordpress.com/tag/genitals/). Further inspiration might be found there, too. [***Muff***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=muff), for example, appears to be attested from the 1690s. Not mediaeval, of course, but still with a reputable history.

I do hope I got the gist of the question right. When saying *female reproductive organs*, you weren't thinking about the ovaries, were you?

Comment: Analog to *oyster*: [conch](http://www.heedthehedonist.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/StoneSoup_VaginaMonologues_Postcard.jpg)

Comment: Oh my gosh that article was a really good read, thanks for sharing it, and for the suggestions as well!

Comment: I suppose the fact that _vanilla_ means ‘little vagina’ is relevant to this (though it’s not really a direct link between female genitals and food, but both of them being shaped like a sheath).

Comment: @Janus It seems to answer the case (shape, aphrodisiac...) _but_ it might take some writing skill to make readers take the hint if used as a metaphor in the sense required here, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Fear not using the word **[cunt](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/11/c-word.html)**, since it was not considered taboo in public speech until 15c.

> cunt (n.) "female intercrural foramen,"
>   or, as some 18c. writers refer to it, "the monosyllable," Middle
>   English cunte "female genitalia," by early 14c. (in Hendyng's
>   "Proverbs" -- ʒeve þi cunte to cunni[n]g, And crave affetir wedding),
>   akin to Old Norse kunta, Old Frisian, Middle Dutch, and Middle Low
>   German kunte, from Proto-Germanic *kunton, which is of uncertain
>   origin. Some suggest a link with Latin cuneus "wedge," others to PIE
>   root *geu- "hollow place," still others to PIE *gwen-, root of queen
>   and Greek gyne "woman."
>
> The form is similar to Latin cunnus "female pudenda" (also, vulgarly,
>   "a woman"), which is likewise of disputed origin, perhaps literally
>   "gash, slit," from PIE *sker- (1) "to cut," or literally "sheath,"
>   from PIE *kut-no-, from root *(s)keu- "to conceal, hide."  Hec vulva:
>   a cunt. Hic cunnus: idem est. [from Londesborough Illustrated
>   Nominale, c. 1500, in "Anglo-Saxon and Old English Vocabularies," eds.
>   Wright and Wülcker, vol. 1, 1884]  First known reference in English
>   apparently is in a compound, Oxford street name Gropecuntlane cited
>   from c. 1230 (and attested through late 14c.) in "Place-Names of
>   Oxfordshire" (Gelling & Stenton, 1953), presumably a haunt of
>   prostitutes. **Used in medical writing c. 1400, but avoided in public
>   speech since 15c.; considered obscene since 17c**.

[**Etymonline**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cunt)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a word that is neither too clinical nor too raunchy, the word [**sex**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sex) can be used as a euphemism for genitals, male or female. **Womanhood** can be used if you want something specifically feminine. Both of these are often used in the more explicit kinds of romantic fiction.

Answer (score 3):

A common mediterranean euphemism is **[fig](http://www.definition-of.com/FIG)**; a pretty mild term, not particularly vulgar, but at the same time quite graphic and easily understood.

> 1. The female genitalia. **The fig was, in ancient Greece, a euphemism for the vagina**; the fig also reminds us of the bible and Adam and Eve dressed in fig leaves in the Garden of Eden; the forbidden fruit is believed to have been a fig, not an apple. Figs , the testicles. In nothing but a fig leaf , naked. In ancient Dionysian festivals, however, the fig symbolized both the penis and the vagina.
>      (TFD)

**Groin** a term which is still used today and won't have your average reader searching for their dictionary. The word is derived from the Middle English   *grynde* (1400), and it is used euphemistically to mean the genitals especially men's testicles, but not exclusively.

Another modern euphemistic term, which has an unsuspecting long history, is **private parts** it evolved from  the sixteenth-century *[privy parts](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/privy-parts)*,  Middle English *[privy member](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/privy-member?q=privy%20member)*, and 13th century *[privy chose](http://www.definition-of.com/privy+chose)*, the word *chose* being French for *thing*.

Comment: Don't be fooled, Medieval England was just as slutty, if not more so than in the 21st century :)

Comment: Nice girls like you shouldn't know about things like this!

Comment: Related because the question is about the Old English word for the fruit *medlar*, which was simply called "open-arse" otherwise spelt as *openærs* http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244408/did-the-english-call-a-fruit-open%C3%A6rs-for-700-years

Comment: @WS2 — I am no feminist and would never castrate the English language with "gender-neutral" neologisms, for example, but someone has to tell you that your comment is completely out of order. You are not commenting on what Mari-Lou A wrote, but the fact that an answer about the names of female genitalia is made by a woman. Now I see that both of you have been on this list a long time and it may be that she will not find the remark offensive, but any other female list member would be justified in doing so and be discouraged from posting. An apology and withdrawal is in order.

Comment: @David I was not offended in the slightest, it's only a joke. I'm 50 years old, calling me a girl was actually quite sweet. We can still joke about our genders and stereotypes, can't we?

Comment: I'm glad about that, and I certainly make jokes about sex (I'm a biologist and leave genders for Italian nouns). And, of course, I wouldn't hesitate to use the joke myself. But I think these are best made face to face, as you will be well aware, visual cues influence how a listner interprets the meaning of what is said. I leave it to @WS2 to consider whether his joke was ill considered in the context of SE EL&U. A gentle apology to the list would not be too difficult and show consideration.

Comment: I can see how the comment *might* be perceived as being patronising to an outsider, but anyone who knows us on ELU will know that I wasn't offended, and WS2's comment was an example of  tongue firmly wedged, nay,  superglued  in cheek :) Still it just goes to show how comments can be misinterpreted in good faith (makes note to self).

Comment: @Mari-LouA lol xx

Comment: @WS2 — http://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice : "Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive." One would expect the "high reputation" members of SE to be especially concerned to show an example of correct behaviour. Apparently not.

Comment: @David perhaps you are unaware of this, but every time a comment is posted beneath a question or answer the author is notified, so I feel a certain responsibility. There are instances of vulgar language used against members, insults (name calling etc) , false accusations and general bickering which are carried on for days on ELU, WS2's comment is none of these. Thank you for the concern, but as I already mentioned, twice, no offence was intended and none was taken.

Answer (score 2):

Shakespeare uses "nothing" as a pun. ("Her nothing", etc.) I won't go grab the exact verses, but you can do so easily. If you want to be strictly Medieval, you'd have to consider whether this might fit.

Comment: Great suggestion:   HAMLET: ACT 3, SCENE 2 His words become especially obscene when one knows that “nothing” was Elizabethan slang for a woman’s lady bits. http://mentalfloss.com/article/54442/10-shakespeares-best-dirty-jokes

Comment: @Josh61 exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You could put a spin on '**Never regions**'

Nether region may refer to: Hell, the Underworld, or any place of darkness or eternal suffering. Subterranea (geography) Euphemism or slang for the buttocks, groin and genitals of human body, separately or collectively.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nether_region

Answer (score 0):

***Quim*** from 1735 era, should work for your book. It also sounds soft and feminine.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quim) defines it as

> (British, vulgar slang) A woman's genitals.

Answer (score 0):

What about something multifaceted like “her host?” This seems to take into account the physiological, alimentary, religious, social, etc. aspects of the female sexual organ.