# Etymology of "arse-smart" as a name for the water pepper

Tags: etymology

Today I learned that water pepper (*Persicaria hydropiper, L. 1800*) is otherwise called "arse-smart" in English:

> PERSICARIA, Arse-smart
>    The *Characters are;
>
>   It is a Plant with an apetalous Flower having several* Stamina *or Chives which arise from the multisid* Calyx: *the Pointal afterward becomes an oval-pointed smooth Seed, inclosed in the Capsule, which was before the Flower-cup: to which may be added, It hath jointed Stalks, and the Flowers are produced in Spikes.*

—[The Gardeners Dictionary](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NuRi8m3xvykC&hl=ru&pg=PP64#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1754)

I failed to find its etymology in OED or other sources.

What could be the etymology of this name?

Comment: I’ve never even heard of water pepper, much less arsesmart!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's a different sense of *smart* in this case, though.

Comment: Have you Googled the term?

Comment: @Kris I have, yes, that's how I found it on Google Books

Comment: Much before that, right at the top of the search results are the pointers to the answer.

Comment: @Kris: I'm not seeing any. In my yield, the only link which mentions "arse-smart" and not "smart-arse" from the first ten leads to this question, but naturally that wasn't the case before I posted it.

Comment: Don't wipe with it or your arse will smart >>> arse-smart.

Comment: This is a smart-arse question :-)

Comment: Loosely related: [Did the English call a fruit “openærs” for 700 years?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244408/did-the-english-call-a-fruit-open%C3%A6rs-for-700-years)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Arsesmart* (variously spelled) is first attested in the OED around 1300, as *ersmert*, an alternative name for water pepper.

The origin is assumed to be simple composition, *arse* referring to a person's buttocks and *smart* in the verb sense of feeling pain, as asserted by [John Minsheu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Minsheu) in his 1617 *Ductor in Linguas* (*Guide into Tongues*):

> Ἡγεμὼν είς τὰς γλῶσσας: Ductor in Linguas 544
>   Arsmart..because if it touch the taile or other bare skinne, it
>   maketh it smart, as often it doth, being laid into the bed greene to
>   kill fleas.

Answer (score 9):

Wiktionary provides the following etymology:

[Arse-smart](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/arsesmart)

> From arse +‎ smart, because the plant stings when it touches bare skin, and was often laid in beds to kill fleas.

[image]

(http://plants-of-styria.uni-graz.at/images/persicaria)

Comment: somehow I missed the wiktionary, thanks! do you know the original source for that?